# If text-selection is inside a specific div

Tags: javascript

I am using `contenteditable=true` trying make a text editor. I have successfully used `getSelection()` to wrap the selection inside HTML tags.

A problem is though, that if the user selects text outside the editor and the operation button is clicked, that text will be wrapped inside tags as well.

How would I do it with `getSelection()`, check if the selection is inside a div with the class of editor?

**Edit:**

Currently using this code:

```
var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange();

if(sel.getRangeAt){
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var newNode = document.createElement("p");
    newNode.setAttribute('class', operationClass);
    range.surroundContents(newNode);
} else {
    sel.pasteHTML('<p class="' +  operationClass +'">'+sel.htmlText+'</p>');
}
```

Comment: I've removed the jQuery tag from the question. You're not using the library.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I am using it, just not in this function as getSelection() dont work with it. If there is any uptodate solutions using JQuery i would use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have `var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);` you can determine if `range.commonAncestorContainer` or one of its ancestors is the editor container, using code like this:

```
var ancestor = range.commonAncestorContainer;
while (ancestor.id != "editor" // Check id, class or otherwise
       && ancestor.parentElement != null) {
    ancestor = ancestor.parentElement;
}

if (ancestor.id == "editor") {
    // Selection is within the editor.
}
```

Comment: The parentElement isn't always .editor, the html could look like this: <div> <p> <div> <b> <p class="left-align"> </p> </b> </div> </p> </div> or even more worse depending on how the user interacted.

Comment: @SamPettersson, I'm sorry if I was unclear. I meant for you to check if the editor container is one of the _ancestors_, not just the _parent_. I'll edit my answer with a more elaborate example shortly.

Comment: I was able to reach the container class using ancestor.parentNode.className although it worked first click the second click and all clicks after that makes ancestors contain the selection?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with _second click_. Could you elaborate or post a code sample?